# Why "#define OPERATION(op) x op=value" macro gives me "error: expected primary-expression before '=' token" in g++?

Tags: macros, g++

Following code snippet:

```
#define OPERATION(op) x op= value
...
OPERATION(*)
```

Output should be "x*= value" that would be perfectly fine in my scope.
It works perfectly well in visual studio.

But here i get: "error: expected primary-expression before '=' token"
Seems its not replaceing the op  because there is no seperator behind it?
How can i get it working in g++?
I tried with more version of g++, with the latest too.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I vote to close because it has already been answered (while very technical answer) in the mentioned link. But you can solve your problem by defining `#define OPERATION(op) x op value)` and using it with `OPERATION(*=)`.

Comment: Sure. But it was strange for first look :)